# Finding missing month from my table

Tags: sql

I have a table with month column. I want to find rows which have missing month in it.Following is the table:

```
NUMBER MONTH
A      2016-04-01
A      2016-06-01
A      2016-07-01
B      2016-03-01
B      2016-04-01
B      2016-05-01
```

from the above table I want to find missing numbers which have missing month `'2016-05-01'` (Missing May month)

Comment: do you have a master table that holds all the months info?

Comment: no. this is the only one table

Comment: What is a missing month? Why is it `2016-05-01`, rather than say `2012-01-01` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?