# Find missing months in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this post remains unanswered and not useful
[Finding missing month from my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509393/finding-missing-month-from-my-table)

This link [Get Missing Month from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717597/get-missing-month-from-table) requires a lookup table... which is not my first choice.

I have a table with Financial Periods, and a reference number. Each reference numbers has a series of financial periods which may start anywhere, and end anywhere. The test is simply that between the start and end, there is no gap - i.e. there must be every financial period period the smallest and largest dates, when grouped by reference number.

A financial period is a month.

So... in this example below, Reference Number A is missing May 2016.

```
REF    MONTH
A      2016-04-01
A      2016-06-01
A      2016-07-01
B      2016-03-01
B      2016-04-01
B      2016-05-01
C      2022-05-01



-- Find the boundaries of each ref
select REF
, MIN(Month) as smallest
, MAX(Month) as largest
from myTable
group by REF

-- But how to find missing items?
```

SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Create a date table as shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) and LEFT OUTER JOIN it with your myTable, then you can filter by missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly a Calendar Table would make this a small task (among many others)

Here is an alternative using the window function `lead() over()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([REF] varchar(50),[MONTH] date)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A','2016-04-01')
,('A','2016-06-01')
,('A','2016-07-01')
,('B','2016-03-01')
,('B','2016-04-01')
,('B','2016-05-01')
,('C','2022-05-01')

;with cte as ( 
Select *
      ,Missing = datediff(MONTH,[Month],lead([Month],1) over (partition by Ref order by [Month]))-1
 From @YourTable
 )
 Select * from cte where Missing>0
```

**Results**

```
REF MONTH       Missing
A   2016-04-01  1
```

Comment: Thanks for that pointer to `LEAD()` - never seen that before.

Comment: @Maxcot The window functions are well worth your time getting comfortable with them.

Comment: @Maxcot  When you have a few moments.   https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/

Comment: But 2016-04-01 is in the original data.  It's not missing.

Comment: @dougp No but it is a quick and easy way to identify the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more row of input to demonstrate the solution better.

```
with forecast (
  REF,
  [MONTH]
) as (
  select REF
  , [MONTH]
  from (
    values
        ('A', {d '2016-04-01'})
      , ('A', {d '2016-06-01'})
      , ('A', {d '2016-07-01'})
      , ('B', {d '2016-03-01'})
      , ('B', {d '2016-04-01'})
      , ('B', {d '2016-05-01'})
      , ('B', {d '2016-09-01'})
      , ('C', {d '2022-05-01'})
    ) x (REF, [MONTH])
),
--  define the date ranges
daterange as (
  select REF
  , min([MONTH]) as dtmin
  , max([MONTH]) as dtmax
  from forecast
  group by REF
),
--  get all of the [end of month] dates in the range
dt (
  REF,
  [MONTH]
) as (
  select REF
  , dtmin
  from daterange dr
  
  union all
  select dt.REF
  , dateadd(month, 1, [MONTH])
  from dt dt
    inner join daterange dr on dr.REF = dt.REF
  where dateadd(month, 1, [MONTH]) <= dr.dtmax
)
--  find the missing months

select REF
, [MONTH]
from dt

except
select REF
, [MONTH]
from forecast
order by 1, 2


-- or list all of the months for each REF
--select REF
--, [MONTH]
--from dt
```